# Put html input default values back when page reloads

Tags: html, input

here is the input element:

```html
<body class="container-fluid">
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="20" min="1" max="10000000">
</body>
```

When I change the value in the input, then reload, the changed value stays there and is not set back to the default.

How to I get it to always show the default value on loading?

Comment: Use cookie or localStorage to store the value you want to save and then update the value  of the input with stored value on the reloading page

Comment: surely it shouldn't be that complicated to have the element display the default value (i.e. "20") on loading, should it?

Comment: yes it is without backend side :)